# Download picture from database to display via JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, html, cordova

I am developing mobile applications, and I was thinking, if I need to download a picture from a server, I cannot actually run the PHP natively (I am using a [PhoneGap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhoneGap) type setup), so how could I download a picture from a database, run it though JavaScript and then display it to the user?

I would imagine something like:

1. Ajax request,
2. Return HTML string of binary data
3. Do some stuff to that?

Or

1. Ajax request,
2. Return a HTML string of reference to the picture, for example: `picture1.jpg`.
   In JavaScript, write something like `document.write <img src="http://blahh/img/"+imagePath`

I'm not sure what the best way to do this is.

Comment: Why not creating a PHP script that turn your data into an image and then calling <img src="myimage.php?mayparams" /> ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. How can i turn the data into an image sorry? Do you mean like, myimage.php would echo the image out as a string as if it was normal HTML?

Comment: You echo the binary data with the appropriate [content type headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), you then link to your PHP script as if it were a image with your <img> tags

Comment: I see thanks, so when uploading, how would I upload the binary? Is there a standard method? And i take it the datatype is a blob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my mind, the simplest way to dynamically load external pictures is to get a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) object from a PHP script containing the picture URL (like `http://www.example.com/pictures/getPicture/YOUR_PICTURE_ID`).

#### Server side

```
<?php
    $pictureUrl = 'http://example.com/pictures/picture.jpg'; //You can get it with a database query
    $pictureName = 'Foo';
    $pictureAltText = 'Bar';

    // You can do some stuff here.

    // At the end of the script, write result.
    echo json_encode(compact('pictureUrl', 'pictureName', 'pictureAltText'));
?>
```

#### Client side

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // With jQuery
    $.getJSON('http://www.example.com/pictures/getPicture/YOUR_PICTURE_ID', function(data){
        console.log(data.pictureUrl, data.pictureName, pictureAltText);

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = data.pictureUrl;
        img.setAttribute('alt', data.pictureAltText);

        img.onload = function(){
            // Displaying picture when download completed
            $(img).appendTo('body');
        }
    });
</script>
```

If you don't use jQuery, you have to use [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to get the JSON encoded response and to parse it (you can see the MDN documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but not purely in JavaScript.

Since you mentioned [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), I will go in that direction:

1. make table in database in which you will store all images. You need
   to have some kind of `image_content` field and load every image in
   some baseline64 encoder like:

   http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp. And store
   returned string into that `image_content` field.

   Or you can write some script that will convert all images you want
   to [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) directly in PHP by using `http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php`.
2. make a PHP file. For example, `giveme_encoded_img.php` in that file you
   need to have one parameter in the URL like `gimme_encoded_img.php?image_name=header_bg`.

   Then get `image_name` with `$_REQUEST` and do a MySQL query with that
   data in the `WHERE` statement so that you can select an encoded image string
   from the database.

   After that, just print it.
3. When you do an Ajax request to a file above, just update the desired
   image src with the response. The best way for doing this is to take the response
   and get some element by id, like

   var header_bg = document.getElementById('header_bg');  header_bg.src
   = response;

   The  final HTML needs to look something like this:

   img alt="Embedded Image" id="header_bg" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..."

Baseline64 embedding is really good, especially if you need to embed images in emails, then a lot of email clients show them by default instead of hiding the remote images from your server.

I hope I was clear enough.

Still this is not a purely JavaScript solution.